# HibernateTemplate - find by primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a UserEntity with an auto-generated field called "id". 
I am aware that I can retrieve the result that I want by using

```
hibernateTemplate.find
```

but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Thanks.

[Edit]
My apologies {@JB Nizet}

Expected result: 
same as what this would give,

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT user FROM UserEntity user WHERE user.id = ?", id);
```

where id is a PK in my table.

Comment: Given that we don't know what result you want, how could we tell? BTW, if you read the javadoc of HibernateTemplate, you'll see that Spring recommends not using it anymore.

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks for the heads up. Now that you mentioned it, I'm reading on previously answered questions about HibernateTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of getting an entity by ID is to use `Session.get()` (native Hibernate API), or `HibernateTemplate.get()` (HibernateTemplate api).

Simply reading the javadoc would have told you that.